# How to run Gradle builds in a build environment quickly and safely?

Tags: java, optimization, gradle

I'm working on a project which at one point has to build Java projects with Gradle. My app runs in Docker and I've noticed that Gradle builds are woefully slow (around **16-17 sec**). I've tried to speed them up with using `--daemon` and `--parallel` but this resulted in the Gradle daemons conflicting with each other (I ran the Gradle builds concurrently). So my question is this:

How can I speed up my Gradle builds if I

- Use `ProcessBuilder` to run Gradle
- My project runs in a Docker container
- I build multimodule projects but I can modify the "reactor" project (but not the subprojects)
- Currently I run `gradle assemble` to create my artifacts, I **only run the build to create an artifact which I can use later**
- I don't need to run any tests
- The build runs in the same Docker container again and again so it can take advantage of the local `.gradle` cache

I have the option to run builds concurrently but Gradle is a rather big resource hog so I'd prefer non-concurrent builds.

Comment: @Whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: A gradle build is normally pretty fast. Are you sure you don't download the same resources over and over again?

Comment: I edited my question. Gradle has its own cache within the container so only the first build is supposed to be slow.

Comment: Use `--profile` and maybe a [build scan](https://gradle.com/build-scans) to investigate where you maybe have a performance leak. The [Gradle Performance Guide](https://github.com/gradle-guides/performance) might also help.

Comment: You may see get some additional insight into other issues people have ran into (with some similarities to your setup) in [gradle/851](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851).

Comment: Are you doing something weird with your filesystem?  Such that you could be running into things like this: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/188 ?
Regarding the ProcessBuilder part, one way to sink your build performance would be to mess up handling of the console input/output such that it's not being buffered properly.
You likely need to do some more diagnosis and figure out what exactly is slowing you down.  How fast is a non-docker build of this thing?

Comment: I'm just writing a `build.gradle` file by hand. The problem is not with the `ProcessBuilder`, beacause if I check the Gradle logs I can see that the build itself was slow. I just did a build right now: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 26s`  `5 actionable tasks: 5 executed` This is how I interact with the `ProcessBuilder`: 
            `process.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { gradleOut.append(it.readText()) }`
            `process.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { gradleOut.append(it.readText()) }` (this is Kotlin code)

Comment: I've been finding that my Macbook Pro becomes unresponsive with --parallel. Maybe that should only be used on a build server, not a local machine (on Gradle 4.8.1 anyway).